# POME GRANATE or pom o gra nate

Tags: pronunciation

What is the pronunciation of pomegranate?
When I check the dictionaries for the pronunciation, its different from the way the native speakers pronounce it.
I'm confused what pronunciation should I use.
https://www.lexico.com/definition/pomegranate

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pomegranate

Comment: The second is more common in the US.

Comment: The pronunciations given by Lexico and Cambridge differ in only minor respects, although Lexico makes the first "e" optional in its US pronunciation.  (On the Lexico site, you can't view the UK and US pronunciations both at once but have to switch between Lexico's two sites.)  You haven't told us what pronunciations you're hearing from native speakers.  Given that pronunciation topics are normally not considered suitable anyway, you could at least be specific about your question.  Some words do have multiple pronunciations. The dictionaries generally show the most standard ones.

Answer (score 0):

English has many, many dialects so there is not one single way to pronounce words. Your best bet is to listen to the accent or dialect of the people you want to converse with and then imitate them.

That said, the Cambridge way sounds close to what I'd expect from a (neutral midwest) US or (greater london) UK native speaker.

Comment: so that means  the pronunciation pomo-granate is heard like that because of the accent? And I being a non-native speaker would say 'Pome-granate'.

Comment: @aimisid, Pronounce it however you want. As long as the meaning is clear, no one will notice.

Comment: @aimisid accents are strange things in that they are both formed from your environment but can be steered through practice. The easiest is just to pronounce it the way that seems easiest but it is entirely valid to steer yourself towards a british or american accent, or towards a specific group who might not be native speakers but you'll need to talk to a lot. having a certain accent will communicate things about you, your schooling, class, origins ect..

Comment: It's even possible to have several accents ready to go and switch between them in a practice called "code switching". The main points are that 1. you are comfortable 2. the person you are talking to understands you.

Comment: I speak something reasonably close to RP and I say Pom as in Tom, the -e- is like in leg, and the granate part like granatt. My wife is from Lancashire and she says it the same.

Comment: @Borgh - "having a certain accent will communicate things about you, your schooling, class, origins etc" - tell me about it!